# BitGO - Get account & value from Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

What i'm doing :

- When a new Users register a personal wallet is generated and stored for them inside Mongo.
- Latter we make a request and get all User Wallet addresses from Mongo and store them in `allDBWallets`.
- Every day a new wallet is generated and it's address is stored in `walletId`.
- People send money to `walletId` from their unique generated address and we start logging and analyzing all `walletId` transaction history.

```js
// Check if a wallet has new transactions
var allTransactions = [
     {
        "id": "09829738672b3aa5be23775ba7ee81fb2f8c99f386c8731bc9710d376698073b",
        "normalizedHash": "453e4cb85bf5ad12afa13b017e82f3963a420e6b57c59e50098d0b0a8a850493",
        "date": "2016-06-13T22:51:55.603Z",
        "fee": 30000,
        "inputs": [
           {
              "previousHash": "41cd8c04edd66415718eccd2353e903b95bc172931029667114dd28c6af5597f",
              "previousOutputIndex": 4
           },
           {
              "previousHash": "41cd8c04edd66415718eccd2353e903b95bc172931029667114dd28c6af5597f",
              "previousOutputIndex": 6
           },
           {
              "previousHash": "43e5068fddd8c5a2b340524b471aad74755f625ae9d9d6610d132f56c5acbedb",
              "previousOutputIndex": 0
           },
           {
              "previousHash": "c00bd520180c32687ecb9dc00e9d40f918d5b49c752acbe48a39b4b729fc0a03",
              "previousOutputIndex": 0
           }
        ],
        "outputs": [
           {
              "vout": 0,
              "account": "2Mu1BXKcWGxt1HnMdTTLdtPNVV9xmU94Vih",
              "value": 22890000
           },
           {
              "vout": 1,
              "account": "2N2aohA3TyjLzAsjocHnAHW1zAGtBCvEbPn",
              "value": 27025087
           },
           {
              "vout": 2,
              "account": "2N1mqFS5nDJkPHTvKz1xBFs2LP8LwoKmcBH",
              "value": 705400000,
              "isMine": true,
              "chain": 0,
              "chainIndex": 0
           },
           {
              "vout": 3,
              "account": "2NBJFaWk6WVzwipvAAgQ9aMghhzLu8RL1Bi",
              "value": 19670000
           },
           {
              "vout": 4,
              "account": "2NFbSredn8i7rGhwAY5vGuBzobkjQRKDy5n",
              "value": 14420000
           }
        ],
        "entries": [
           {
              "account": "2NBJFaWk6WVzwipvAAgQ9aMghhzLu8RL1Bi",
              "value": 19670000
           },
           {
              "account": "2N6nyPBXnjUVQiktuAaRd6wkU1FkMgFLja5",
              "value": -287741933
           },
           {
              "account": "2MwgwnZV8sm9nBgjntHjhgEgCP18LtsfEGY",
              "value": -143298154
           },
           {
              "account": "2NFbSredn8i7rGhwAY5vGuBzobkjQRKDy5n",
              "value": 14420000
           },
           {
              "account": "2MzppxEX7xMidjhoJGczFDYsHk5TQwFkjS3",
              "value": -203125000
           },
           {
              "account": "2N1mqFS5nDJkPHTvKz1xBFs2LP8LwoKmcBH",
              "value": 705400000
           },
           {
              "account": "2N2aohA3TyjLzAsjocHnAHW1zAGtBCvEbPn",
              "value": 27025087
           },
           {
              "account": "2MvSR1qPDc27w9knqgCkD3vkGw4svxb4fsL",
              "value": -155270000
           },
           {
              "account": "2Mu1BXKcWGxt1HnMdTTLdtPNVV9xmU94Vih",
              "value": 22890000
           }
        ],
        "confirmations": 183,
        "pending": false,
        "instant": false,
        "blockhash": "0000000000771a83972ddc9d2f45051c5da52b40e3a4c20259ab700880708293",
        "height": 870163
     },
     {
        "id": "41cd8c04edd66415718eccd2353e903b95bc172931029667114dd28c6af5597f",
        "normalizedHash": "ea8540f5e65d1faec9268586d35acfeed97419ac23888a2eef0ed5aa5940aed1",
        "date": "2016-06-13T03:36:04.369Z",
        "fee": 11846,
        "inputs": [
           {
              "previousHash": "92f052103edacef17ae628ed435f64df5740c4a88dd889d57cc04135ace1ed4c",
              "previousOutputIndex": 0
           }
        ],
        "outputs": [
           {
              "vout": 0,
              "account": "2N2jZ3B39oPEVu85V9s74kKwyY4PkoUGuz6",
              "value": 86370000
           },
           {
              "vout": 1,
              "account": "2NBCtYhx4i13F9xyWTU6WixkknYmdpfJaYw",
              "value": 113000000
           },
           {
              "vout": 2,
              "account": "2MtBRRoisqfqKzVsvh6QdHWkcUFYaiDbK82",
              "value": 98630000
           },
           {
              "vout": 3,
              "account": "2N9tXbXxY73KkQNybp5qqFTZu6qN6WRsm7H",
              "value": 130620000
           },
           {
              "vout": 4,
              "account": "2MvSR1qPDc27w9knqgCkD3vkGw4svxb4fsL",
              "value": 155270000
           },
           {
              "vout": 5,
              "account": "2N1mqFS5nDJkPHTvKz1xBFs2LP8LwoKmcBH",
              "value": 85300000,
              "isMine": true,
              "chain": 0,
              "chainIndex": 0
           },
           {
              "vout": 6,
              "account": "2MwgwnZV8sm9nBgjntHjhgEgCP18LtsfEGY",
              "value": 143298154
           }
        ],
        "entries": [
           {
              "account": "2NBCtYhx4i13F9xyWTU6WixkknYmdpfJaYw",
              "value": 113000000
           },
           {
              "account": "2N9tXbXxY73KkQNybp5qqFTZu6qN6WRsm7H",
              "value": 130620000
           },
           {
              "account": "2MwgwnZV8sm9nBgjntHjhgEgCP18LtsfEGY",
              "value": 143298154
           },
           {
              "account": "2N2jZ3B39oPEVu85V9s74kKwyY4PkoUGuz6",
              "value": 86370000
           },
           {
              "account": "2MzppxEX7xMidjhoJGczFDYsHk5TQwFkjS3",
              "value": -812500000
           },
           {
              "account": "2N1mqFS5nDJkPHTvKz1xBFs2LP8LwoKmcBH",
              "value": 85300000
           },
           {
              "account": "2MtBRRoisqfqKzVsvh6QdHWkcUFYaiDbK82",
              "value": 98630000
           },
           {
              "account": "2MvSR1qPDc27w9knqgCkD3vkGw4svxb4fsL",
              "value": 155270000
           }
        ],
        "confirmations": 370,
        "pending": false,
        "instant": true,
        "instantId": "575e2a24b5bdf3f4069ae3f63b015023",
        "blockhash": "00000000003c0e6cd52b31dac16dac5b85a3ea1ccb3637b62fb3930ce29f6c0f",
        "height": 869976
     }

  ]

// Daily Generated Wallet
var walletId = '2N1mqFS5nDJkPHTvKz1xBFs2LP8LwoKmcBH';

//  Get all Users Addresses from Mongo and store them in allDBWallets

var allDBWallets=[];

  User.find({}, (err, docs) => {
    if (err) {console.log('Could not find Wallets in DB');}
       // console.log(docs);
       docs.forEach( (address) => {
       // console.log(address);
       allDBWallets.push(address.userWallet);
    });
 });
        console.log(allDBWallets)
  [ '2MzppxEX7xMidjhoJGczFDYsHk5TQwFkjS3',
  '2NFt8YfydBU5JD9U8Xq2ucbfUp2sP7BjUrh',];

// I'm sure the IF statement is wrong...
allTransactions.forEach(function(transaction){ 
    // console.log(transaction);
    transaction.entries.forEach(function(entry){
      for (var i in allDBWallets){
           // This is where I fail
        if (entry.account == allDBWallets[i] && entry.account == walletId) {
          console.log(entry.account, entry.value);
           // best result would be allDBWallets[i] with walletId entry.value
        }
      }
    })
});
```

*** What I hope to achieve is this***

// First TX OBJ Example

```
{
"account": "2N1mqFS5nDJkPHTvKz1xBFs2LP8LwoKmcBH", // bad address, i need the Users address (2MzppxEX7xMidjhoJGczFDYsHk5TQwFkjS3) not the walletId address
"value": 705400000 // real amount is perfect but can't properly compare and extract users address
},
```

Hope I find someone that can help explain how to validate and extract the Users Address and Real money sent to the Daily Generated address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the following statement

```
if (entry.account == allDBWallets[i] && entry.account == walletId) {
```

Condition 2 (**entry.account == walletId**) will be true only when `entry.account` will be `2N1mqFS5nDJkPHTvKz1xBFs2LP8LwoKmcBH` and in that case condition 1 (**entry.account == allDBWallets[i]**) will be true only when `allDBWallets` array has an entry for `2N1mqFS5nDJkPHTvKz1xBFs2LP8LwoKmcBH`.

And as per above data, both conditions are never true at same time, hence, not getting desired result.

Hence, you need to correct the condition/logic to get the desired output.

**A possible solution**

```
allTransactions.forEach(function(transaction){ 

  // Check whether there is an entry from any of the wallets in allDBWallets
  var wallet = transaction.entries.find(function(entry){
        return allDBWallets.indexOf(entry.account) > -1;
  });

  // If an entry exists, then find entries for walletId and paint 
  if(wallet) {
    transaction.entries.forEach(function(entry){
        if (entry.account == walletId) {
          console.log(wallet.account, entry.value);
        }
    })
  }
});
```